Connecting R to a datawarehouse
I am relatively new to R coding, and certainly new to connecting data. A colleague left me a script to create a connection between our datawarehouse and R. This datawarehouse brings together several streams of live data. My involvement with the datawarehouse so far has been through queries with PostgreSQL, pgAdmin. However, I am unable to run this R script correctly.
I have pasted the script below. However, it is at point 3 where I find the error (or the first error at least)
this code:
drv <- keyring::key_get("NRAdb-driver", username = "NRADWH")

produces this error:
Error in b_wincred_i_get(target) : 
Windows credential store error in 'get': Element not found.

Any help would be great (grateful for any advice on other parts of the script as well)
setup_database_access <- function(database = "NRADWH", host = "10.18.0.250", port = "3128", driver = RPostgres::Postgres())
setup_database_access(database = "NRADWH", host = "10.18.0.250", driver = RPostgres::Postgres())



establish_db_connection <- function(database = "NRADWH") {
  
  stopifnot("Credentials not found. First run 'setup_database_access(...)'" = 
              database %in% keyring::key_list("NRAdb-username")[["username"]] &
              database %in% keyring::key_list("NRAdb-password")[["username"]])
  
  stopifnot("Database mis-configured. Please re-run setup_database_access(...)'" = 
              database %in% keyring::key_list("NRAdb-driver")[["username"]] &
              keyring::key_get("NRAdb-driver", username = database) %in% c("postgres", "mysql"))
  
}

  
drv <- keyring::key_get("NRAdb-driver", username = "NRADWH") 
  
  

  if(drv=="postgres"){ 
    driver <- RPostgres::Postgres()
  } else if (drv == "mysql") { 
    driver <- RMariaDB
    
  

    if (database %in% keyring::key_list("NRAdb-host")[["username"]]){ # retrieve and store the port for use in the connection code
      port <- keyring::key_get("NRAdb-port", username = database)
    } else {
      port <- NULL
    }
    
    
    
    con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = driver, 
                          user = keyring::key_get("NRAdb-username", username = databse),
                          password = keyring::key_get("NRAdb-password", username = database), 
                          host = keyring::key_get("NRAdb-host", username = database),
                          port = port,
                          dbname = database)
    
  }
  

    
NRADWH <- establish_db_connection("NRADWH") 


Hi, and welcome to SO! I don't wish to sound trite or facetious - but can your colleague be of any help? If s/he wrote it, then surely they can see if there are issues? It's all very well doing a hand-over with a working system, but if you're handed something that's busted, it's not your fault/problem - or maybe it is - start from scratch, but that's not really great for your employer?

Hi, thanks for the welcome :) No my colleague has left unfortunately, I should have made this clear. My understanding is that the code was working but there was no 'handover' as such so if/how it was being used is unlear. Getting this script running is preffered to writing from scratch but its not that important really. Still good to get any thoughts on the script above but I'll also start working on a new script.
